# MPI Client/Server

Tags: c++, mpi, openmpi

I have a situation where all processes/nodes need to communicate with each other multiple times. To minimize the overhead of connection establishment, I am trying to simulate an MPI Server on every node, and then every node creates a connection to every other node as a client during startup. Once, the connections are established, nodes use these connections to communicate with each other.

Here is my workflow:

1. Broadcast a cluster name from one node to all other nodes.
2. All nodes use MPI_Open_port(MPI_INFO_NULL, port_name) to receive a machine generated port name.
3. All nodes published their name using MPI_Publish_name(name, MPI_INFO_NULL, port_name). "name" is created as "clusterName-rank". Once all nodes publish their name, I am executing MPI_Barrier to ensure the names are published. All nodes call MPI_Comm_accept(port_name, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_SELF, client) to wait for any connection.
4. Every node looks up the name for other nodes using MPI_Lookup_name(name, MPI_INFO_NULL, c_port_name). Once it gets the name, it calls MPI_Comm_connect(port_name, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_SELF, &nodeConnections[i]) to register a connection to it.

My problem is in step 4. I am able to get the port name for other processes but when I am calling MPI_Comm_connect(), MPI throws an error as below:

**TWO RECEIVES WITH SAME PEER [[WILDCARD],WILDCARD] AND TAG 300 - ABORTING**

Am I approaching the problem in the right way? If yes, can someone please help me how to resolve this problem. If no, can you please hint me in the right direction?

Here is some initial code snippet I am using if it helps.

```
void MPIServer::startServer() {
    MPI_Open_port(MPI_INFO_NULL, port_name);
    char name[DOMP_MAX_CLIENT_NAME];
    snprintf(name, DOMP_MAX_CLIENT_NAME, "%s-%d", clusterName, rank);
    MPI_Publish_name(name, MPI_INFO_NULL, port_name);
    log("Server %s for node %d available at %s\n", name, rank, port_name);

    // First start your own server thread
    serverThread = std::thread(&MPIServer::accept, this);

    // Wait for all nodes to start their server first
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // Now create connection to all other threads
    char c_port_name[MPI_MAX_PORT_NAME];
    for (int i = 0; i < clusterSize; i++) {
      if (i != rank) {
        snprintf(name, DOMP_MAX_CLIENT_NAME, "%s-%d", clusterName, i);
        MPI_Lookup_name(name, MPI_INFO_NULL, c_port_name);
        log("Node %d connecting to client %s at port %s\n", rank, name, c_port_name);
        MPI_Comm_connect(c_port_name, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_SELF, &nodeConnections[i]);
      }
    }
}
// Here is the accept method
void MPIServer::accept() {
    while (true) {
      MPI_Comm *client = new MPI_Comm();
      MPI_Comm_accept(port_name, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_SELF, client);
      log("Node %d received a request\b", rank);
      // Handle in a new thread
      // TODO: Consider using a threadpool instead of spawning thread every time
      std::thread(&MPIServer::handleRequest, this, client);
    }
  }
```

Here is the MPI Version I am using:

```
-bash-4.2$ ompi_info
                 Package: Open MPI mockbuild@x86-041.build.eng.bos.redhat.com
                          Distribution
                Open MPI: 1.10.7
  Open MPI repo revision: v1.10.6-48-g5e373bf
   Open MPI release date: May 16, 2017
                Open RTE: 1.10.7
  Open RTE repo revision: v1.10.6-48-g5e373bf
   Open RTE release date: May 16, 2017
                    OPAL: 1.10.7
      OPAL repo revision: v1.10.6-48-g5e373bf
       OPAL release date: May 16, 2017
                 MPI API: 3.0.0
            Ident string: 1.10.7
```

Comment: are you using the latest (`4.0.1`) version of Open MPI ?

Comment: Added the version details in the post.

Comment: I suggest you try the latest Open MPI, and make sure you `MPI_Init_thread()` with `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE` since your app looks multithreaded.

Comment: Do you mean that I will not face this issue with the latest 4.0.* version of MPI? The reason I am asking is, it will be tricky to persuade the IT department to upgrade MPI on all servers. Bdw, thanks for the MPI_Init_thread() :)

Comment: I said you should give it a try, and all you need is build and install it in your home directory (e.g. no `root` access is required). if it works, then you can talk to your IT department, or keep using the Open MPI you just built.

Comment: IMHO, using boost::mpi is easier than openMPI.